# how to make link for data field retrieve from mysql using php, html?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am displaying some fields from mysql database using php as given in screen shots. Actually each person has lots of data in several tables. The screen shot displaying only few collected from several tables. Now to display all information corresponding to a person it will be easy if the field usn (say 10IS037) is a link such that whenever i click on any usn then it redirects to another page where the whole information will be display using some query. Now i am trying but i can not make any link of us filed. please see the screen shot.
[image]

A portion of Code is here..

```
<?php
            include('includes/login_connection.php');

        //  $query = "select * from personal_details, course_codes";
            $query = "select p.usn, p.name, p.sem, p.year, cg.cur_cgpa, c.cc1, c.cc2, c.cc3, c.cc4, c.cc5, c.cc6, c.cc7, c.cc8, c.cc9 from personal_details p, course_codes c, cgpa_details cg where p.usn = c.usn AND p.usn = cg.usn order by p.usn";

            $run = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); 
            $num=mysql_numrows($run);
            echo "No. of registered students: $num";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){


                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['usn'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['sem'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cur_cgpa'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cc1'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cc2'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cc3'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cc4'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cc5'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cc6'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cc7'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cc8'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cc9'] . " </td>";
                echo "</tr>";

    //      echo "</table>";    


            }
            mysql_close($bd);

?>
```

And html part is given in pics.. sorry i can not paste text

![enter image description here][2]

```
<table border='1' align="center" style="font-size:14px" width="95%" cellspacing="3" class="db_table" >

<tr class="db_table_tr" >
 <th class="db_table_th" >USN</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Name</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Sem</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Year</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >CGPA</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Subject-1</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Subject-2</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Subject-3</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Subject-4</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Subject-5</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Subject-6</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Subject-7</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Subject-8</th>
 <th class="db_table_th" >Subject-9</th>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question and provide your code.

Comment: 99 times out of 100 the screenshot attached to a question is either totally useless, or would be better presented as text. Code and your database schema speak volumes. This screenshot is confusing, though points for not having any embarrassing tabs open.

Comment: but i can not upload.. shows error due to <tr> tag

Comment: Are you trying to create a link to redirect to a different page for each USN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The echo's are generally not considered good PHP coding practice and your PHP code is not correctly drawing the table (It's missing the table header). However, having said that, using your coding style.

Change the line

```
echo "<td>" . $row['usn'] . " </td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td> <a href='http://somedomain/somepath/usn_handler.php?usn='" . $row['usn'] .
     "' >" . $row['usn'] . "<a/> </td>";
```

Please note I am not correcting your code, as there is a lot I can see wrong. Please do so yourself.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957104/how-to-use-get-method-in-a-session

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $link = $row['usn'];
?>
<td><a href="filename.php?usn=<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $link; ?></a></td>
```

But am concerned you can write PHP without knowing basic HTML