# how to use get method in a session?

Tags: php, session

here is my code. actually i am displaying some data from mysql on the page and creating dynamic link.i want started a session with session_start() in the very begining of code before starting any code. i want to store the value of the link that is to be display on other pagepage..

page1.php

```
 <a style="color:#F00; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-left:33px; font-weight:bold">      
      No. of registered students:
 </a>
<table border='1' align="center" style="font-size:14px" width="95%" cellspacing="3" class="db_table">
<tr class="db_table_tr" >

<th class="db_table_th" name="submit">USN</th>
</tr>
<?php
include('includes/login_connection.php');

    $query = "select p.usn, p.name from personal_details p, course_codes c where p.usn = c.usn order by p.usn";

    $run = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); 
    $num = mysql_numrows($run);         
    echo $num;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href = page2.php" . ">" . $row['usn'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . " </td>";

        if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
            $_SESSION['session_usn'] = $_GET['usn'];
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    mysql_close($bd);

?>
</table>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['session_usn']))
    {
        $_POST['usn'] = $_SESSION['session_usn'];
        echo $_POST['usn'];
    }


?>
```

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: thanks. i will use mysqli

Comment: Did you try `session_start();` in `page1.php`?

Comment: please post only the *relevant* code. we don't need to see all your `<th>`s, other html, and `echo` statements that aren't relevant to the question. posting so much code makes it difficult for others to understand both **where** and **what** the problem is.

Comment: I can't see `session_start()` in `page1.php`

Comment: @sgroves.. edited.....@akam... i posted minimum portion of code, i used session_start() in the very begining that is not posted.

Comment: anyone please answer...

Comment: please `var_dump($_SESSION);` in page1.php after include connection file.

Comment: what is the URL fed to this page?  If it doesn't have a `?submit=XXX` somewhere, your `if(isset($_GET['submit'])){` will never respond.  You should have an `}else{` tagged onto that `isset`.

Comment: @Bora..I already started session while login..so when var_dump() is used it shows only username and password value

Comment: @sable Foste... What is the code for else statement

Comment: @SableFoste You right. `$_GET['submit']` not defined. Sakir Alam, what your `$_GET['submit']`?

Comment: @Bora... can you please tell me how to define it

Comment: what's da meaning of `PSA`? public service announcement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a fall-back, in case the URL provided does not contain the proper variables in the `$_GET` section.

You have:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['session_usn'] = $_GET['usn'];
}
```

You should do something else if `$_GET['submit']` isn't set:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['session_usn'] = $_GET['usn'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['session_usn'] = "unset";
    // or set a warning flag like "unset"
}
```

You should be feeding your php file a url like:

```
http://yoururl.com/page1.php?usn='333'
```

Where 333 is the value you want to store.

Comment: ...so, what is the value stored in `$_SESSION['session_usn']` after adding this?  After the closing bracket of the `else`, enter `echo $_SESSION['session_usn']`  What is the output shown on the screen?

Comment: array(4) { ["SESS_MEMBER_ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["SESS_FIRST_NAME"]=> string(5) "username" ["SESS_LAST_NAME"]=> string(6) "abcxyz" ["session_usn"]=> string(5) "unset" } 2unsetunset

Comment: So this shows that your `$_GET['usn']` doesn't exist.  You web browser bar doesn't have the `?usn='333'` part that I listed in the end of the answer.

Comment: You assign the url in your web brower's URL bar.  If you were going to go to google.com, you would type `google.com` in the web browser URL bar.

Comment: trying to use it in href... not comming

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34493/discussion-between-sable-foste-and-sakir-alam)