# how to create checkbox before each row in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

can anybody please tell me how to create check box before each row while displaying data from mysql. If i retrieve 10 rows then the number of checkboxes must be 10 such that i can select one of rows for further operation

```
<?php

    $query = "select p.usn, p.name, p.sem, p.year, cg.cur_cgpa, c.cc1, c.cc2, c.cc3, c.cc4, c.cc5, 
                    c.cc6, c.cc7, c.cc8, c.cc9 from personal_details p, course_codes c, cgpa_details cg 
              where p.usn = c.usn AND p.usn = cg.usn order by p.usn";

    $run = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); 
    $num = mysql_numrows($run);
    // echo "No. of registered students: $num";
    echo $num;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td ><a href = info.php?id=" . ">" . $row['usn'] . "</a>" . "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['sem'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cur_cgpa'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cc1'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cc2'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cc3'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cc4'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cc5'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cc6'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cc7'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cc8'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cc9'] . " </td>";

        if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
            $_SESSION['session_usn'] = $_GET['usn'];
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=html+checkbox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: add the html for a check box in a td, what's the problem?

Comment: and? you are going to need to be more descriptive than that

Comment: Can you post the code showing where you tried? I don't see it in your question.

Comment: Actually i want to solve the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957104/how-to-use-get-method-in-a-session

Comment: <td><input type="checkbox" name="a_name" value=""></td> for every tr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new  to your table and place a checkbox into it.

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]" value="' . $row['usn'] . '"></td>';
```

Then continue with your original code.

Comment: thanks a lot.. so i need to use ticked[] to post that value???

Comment: Yes $_POST['ticked'] will itself be an array $_POST['ticked'][0], $_POST['ticked'][1] etc